# How come I got undefined variable error?

Tags: php, explode

My code:

```
$fburl_arr = array();
$fburl_arr = explode( "/", "https://www.facebook.com/media/albums/?id=2243618684625465217" );
echo "<pre style='font-size:13px; background-color:yellow;'>";
print_r( "fburl_arr >>> " );
print_r( $fburl_arr );
print_r( "filename >>> " );
print_r( $filename );
echo "</pre>";
```

Gives me the error:

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: fburl_arr in /home/content/96/8564996/html/app/webroot/test/joomla254/modules/mod_jfbalbum/helper.php on line 44
```

Comment: line 44 is a blank line.. really strange..

Comment: Sounds like some code isn't current :)

Comment: Are you including an other .php file at the top of this one? Sometimes, the error is located after the other file was included, causing this kind of error.

Comment: Man, i reloaded the file from filezilla, it was in different format, the $fburl_arr is inline with a comment. how was that happend? :))

Comment: You're welcome! Those are some of the most annoying unexpected issues to deal with :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fburl_arr` is initiated, so that can't be the source of error.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/IP0RCu#

You don't need to initiate the array either, so you can remove

```
$fburl_arr = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open PHP.ini and find config line: **error_reporting**. Change it to: `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` and error will disappear